# Can't import the named export 'CryptoOps' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I am trying to update MSAL library (@azure/msal-browser) in my react app to v3.x (specifically from 2.14.2 to 3.2.0) but gives me this error after npm start:

./node_modules/@azure/msal-browser/dist/crypto/SignedHttpRequest.mjs Can't import the named export 'CryptoOps' from non EcmaScript module (only default export is available)

How can I fix this problem?

The reason why I want to update my MSAL library: Since the latest update of Google Chrome my Teams web app project shows a login popup for any API calls. It shows a popup every time for a second, verifies by itself, and goes away. I can see that my Local Storage is empty and clientIds are not already saved.

After updating to @azure/msal-browser@3.2.0 I expected to resolve my problem with the popup shown in my Teams web app. However, I have a problem executing the app. It gives me the compile error I mentioned above.

Answer (score 0):

In the end, we resolved it simply by disabling the "Experimental third-party storage partitioning" of the Google Chrome flag feature.

1. You can do it by going to this link to see the Google Chrome flags: chrome://flags/
2. Then search for "Experimental third-party storage partitioning"
3. Then change the value of "Default" to "Disabled".

[You can see the screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HL0Sy.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).